# jQuery tabs: Disable window location hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash, tabs

I have a small snippet of which it takes you from one tab to another.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <a href="#tab1">General Settings</a>
    <a href="#tab2">Keyboard Shortcuts</a>
    <a href="#tab3">Regional Settings</a>
    <a href="#tab4">Reset to Defaults</a>
</ul>

<div id="tab1" class="hide">This is tab 1</div>
<div id="tab2" class="hide">his is tab 2</div>
<div id="tab3" class="hide">his is tab 3</div>
<div id="tab4" class="hide">his is tab 4</div>
```

and the jQuery looks like this:

```
$('#tabs a').live('click',function(e){
    var a = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
            $('div.hide:not(#' + a + ')').hide();
            $('#' + a).fadeIn();

    });
```

Now I want to disable the hash tags so they don't appear in the URL bar.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HSJHp/show

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSJHp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this...

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <a href="" id="tablink1">General Settings</a>
    <a href="" id="tablink2">Keyboard Shortcuts</a>
    <a href="" id="tablink3">Regional Settings</a>
    <a href="" id="tablink4">Reset to Defaults</a>
</ul>

<div id="tab1" class="hide">This is tab 1</div>
<div id="tab2" class="hide">his is tab 2</div>
<div id="tab3" class="hide">his is tab 3</div>
<div id="tab4" class="hide">his is tab 4</div>
```

and the jquery looks like this:

```
$('#tabs a').live('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var a = $(this).attr('id').split('tablink')[1];
console.log(a)
        $('div.hide:not(#tab' + a + ')').hide();
        $('#tab' + a).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to use href ?  If you don't, this can be achieved like this

```
$(".tab-content").hide().filter(":eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").fadeIn();
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/diode/mcQpF/1/

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand from your question and code you are trying to implement Tabs. You can easily implement tabs using jQueryUI. Here is the link for it. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

**Update**:
Here is a solution based on what you had implemented. In your solution you are not using li tags inside the ul tags. So this would result in invalid html and can cause issues in different browsers. Here is the updated code with a valid html.
http://jsfiddle.net/byeGu/

Comment: @jQuerybeast you should only downvote if the answer given is specifically wrong, not just if it doesn't give you the answer you're after. It negatively effects your reputation too, so you should only use it for 'BAD' answers. I'll remove mine to please you.

Comment: @jQuerybeast I don't know why you downvoted my answer. Anyways, let me know if you don't want to use jqueryUI tabs, I can help you on your method.

Comment: @beardtwizzle Well I consider both as wrong answer. You've mentioned in a way that it is not possible to achieve what I was trying where a two letter word would be my answer. I can't consider that anything but wrong. As far as virendra's answer, my question was not how to create/use tabs but how to remove the hash from the URL. Providing a link onto a demo/introduction on how to use tabs of which require an entire new library (jQuery UI), I consider that wrong aswell.

Comment: @Virendra Also searching google for 'jquery tabs' and pasting the first link as answer is definitely wrong as an answer but it is considered as a bad answer too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: @jQuerybeast I use Tabs everyday in my development and I know how it can sometimes become a pain to implement. It is lot easier to implement them using jQueryUI and hence I was pointing you to the link for its demo. Also, I was providing an alternative to your solution of implementing tabs.